# Tell if an line is hidden

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart that has multiple lines, each of which is plotted on it's own y-axis.

I have been trying to set it up so that when a line is hidden via the legend the axis it is on is hidden as well. My plan is to add a click listener to the canvas and from there disable or enable all axis depending on the line state.

My issue is determining if the line is hidden or not. The `dataset.hidden` property only seem to be relevant if the hidden value in the `dataset._meta` is undefined. I tried to set up code with this in mind:

```
ctx.onclick = function(){
    var changed = false;
    for(var j = 0;j < scatterChart.options.scales.yAxes.length;j++){
        var oldVal = scatterChart.options.scales.yAxes[j].display;
        var hidden = false;
        var isHiddenDataSet = scatterChart.data.datasets[j].hidden;

        if(isHiddenDataSet){
            hidden = true;
        }

        var isHiddenMeta = scatterChart.data.datasets[j]._meta[0].hidden;
        if(isHiddenMeta != null){
            hidden = isHiddenMeta;
        }

        scatterChart.options.scales.yAxes[j].display = !hidden;
        changed = changed || oldVal == scatterChart.options.scales.yAxes[j].display;
    }
    if(changed){
        scatterChart.update();
    }
}
```

This code worked for my original test that only have one chart but fails if there are more than one chart on the page as the index of the data object in `_meta` changes from chart to chart.

Is there a way to determine if a dataset is hidden?

Comment: `_meta` doesn't work has expected when working with more than one chart. Could you try replacing `_meta[0]` with `_meta[Object.keys(scatterChart.data.datasets[j]._meta)[0]]` ?

Comment: @tektiv That gets the job done. I figured there was some kind of reflective answer like that but wasn't sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Since it works for you, I'm setting it as an answer*

The `_meta` property in your datasets is very useful, especially when searching for specific properties such as `hidden`.
However it is quite difficult to handle it when there are several charts on the same page.

When doing the following :

```js
var isHiddenMeta = scatterChart.data.datasets[j]._meta[0].hidden;
```

The `0` index is actually the first chart called in your code (*index `1` is the second, etc..*)
So you'll get the information of the first chart, and not the one you just clicked on.

---

To fix this, you need to use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method coupled with your dataset information, as follows :

```js
var isHiddenMeta = scatterChart.data.datasets[j]._meta[Object.keys(scatterChart.data.datasets[j]._meta)[0]].hidden;
```

This will get you the `hidden` property of the dataset of the real chart.

Comment: @ tektiv -- this works great but isn't there a more elegant alternative as of 2021?

Comment: @Joe-ElasticsearchHandbook I cannot tell, it has been a while I haven't worked with Chart.js. In any case, you could create a util function to encapsulate it and use it to make it more readable (e.g `getMetaData(chartIndex, datasetIndex).hidden`)

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I did! Thx